# Does everything in the OnStart() (even if I use override async) get executed before MainPage is called

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code in my App.Xaml.cs

```
    protected override async void OnStart()
    {
        App.DB.CreateTables();
        App.DB.GetSettings();
        App.DB.PopulateTables();
    }
```

Is it the case that all three of these methods will be 100% executed and completed before methods in the constructor of:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the OnStart() is async, and you are not waiting, then, it's not 100% sure that you will navigate to the MainPage before they are executed.

If those methods, are not UI related, you can just:

```
protected override async void OnStart()
    {
          Task.Run(async()=>{ await YourMethods(); }).Wait();

    }
```

Comment: For the code above that you added, if that was the only line in the OnStart() , does the OnStart() need to be async?

Comment: Yes, you need to override it, so it must always be async

Comment: Never use `.Wait()`